# Populating static string buffer in C via snprintf

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, printf

I have some buffer and known size

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024*1024
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

I must populate this buffer with some complex string.

```
int populate_string(char *buffer) {
    char *tbuffer = buffer;
    size_t tsize = BUFFER_SIZE;
    int rv;

    rv = snprintf(tbuffer, tsize, "foobar %s %d %s %D", ...);
    if (rv < 0) {
        printf("snprintf() error");
        return -1;
    } else if (rv >= tsize) {
        printf("overflow, increase buffer size");
        return -1;
    } else {
        tsize -= rv;
        tbuffer += rv;
    }

    // repeat snprintf's until string is fully populated

    return 0;
}
```

So, I have three questions:

1. Is this the best way for dynamically populating static string?
2. Is my way of populating string safe?
3. How can I reduce number of lines? These return value checks take a lot of place, especially if there is lot of snprintfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open_memstream and fmemopen might be of interest for you:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream

You can populate your buffer by opening a file stream to the buffer, i.e.:

```
FILE *f=fmemopen(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,"w");
fwrite(f,...);
```

Writing to this stream will yield an error (if you disable buffering) when you hit the ceiling of "buffer".

Also, you can use open_memstream to create a stream on a memory which automatically resizes to hold what you write to it.

Comment: open_memstream and fmemopen are not portable, unfortunately. They are not available on Windows, OSX, iOS, *BSD, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on what you do with this strings then :) Obvious alternative is to use linked lists instead.
2. Yes, it's safe.
3. Sometimes there is no need to check whether it snprintf error or overflow - so you can use only one if() check.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to use `snprintf`, assuming that the buffer length you are using is accurate.  If the buffer length decreases, you would run into problems.  Instead of using `tsize` to store the length of the buffer, have the caller pass in the buffer length as a parameter.  That should make your function re-usable for different buffer sizes.  You would still have to trust that the value provided by the caller is accurate, but I suppose you can't completely error-proof the function.

If you want to reduce your line count, combine multiple `snprintf` calls into one.  That should reduce the number of error-checking blocks that are required.  The drawback is you might run out of buffer midway through a string, but I don't think your current code protects against that either.  To do that, you'd have to print to a temporary, internal string, measure that string's length, and then copy it to the output buffer if and only if there is enough room left.

Comment: When talking about reducing line count, I thought about using some kind of macros or function with variable number of arguments to move error checking from my function.

Comment: In my experiences, it's usually not a good idea to wrap up error handling in a macro.  If you are only doing that with your "print error message and return -1" blocks though, they're probably trivial enough to not cause too many problems.